# ColorFul Text For Logging In Wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpf, logging, data-binding

I have a wpf app for for logging the error, general information and warning. These information also get displayed to the user in a text block of app so user can also see the errors and other information.

But right now the color for the text for error warning and success is hard coded as dark grey.

The job I have to do is to make it displayed in different colors Example (Success should be displayed in green color, Error should be red and general info in dark gray). I tried data binding but I can not achieve this. I need some help in this.
Below I am sharing relevant code needed.

MainWindow.Xaml Code

```
ListView Height="230"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding EventLogList}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel Width="560">
                            <TextBlock Foreground="DarkGray"
                                       Text="{Binding}"
                                       TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                        </WrapPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
public ObservableCollection<string> EventLogList
    {
        get => _eventLogList;
        set => Set(ref _eventLogList, value);
    }
protected sealed override void LogInfoEvent(string msg)
    { 

        EventLogList.Insert(0, $"{_logDate} [Info]: {msg}");
        base.LogInfoEvent(msg);
    }

    protected sealed override void LogErrorEvent(string msg, Exception exception = null)
    {
        if (IsScanningMode)
            StopScanningExecuteAsync();

        EventLogList.Insert(0, $"{_logDate} [Error]: {msg}");
        base.LogErrorEvent(msg, exception);
        
    }
```

Comment: Please share where do you get Log Level, because I can't spot it in code

Comment: In the mainwindowviewmodel.cs there are several functions for the detection of several error and informative message these function push/add a string message in the event loglist and this log list is displayed on every event in a listview.

Comment: Ok, how do you know message is successful or information?

Comment: So if there is an error the log message will start like <date> <time> [Error]: <log message>. If it a general info than message will start like <date> <time> [Info]: <log message>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, change log entry type. I defined a new object. `ValueTuple` won't work, because its members aren't properties.

```cs
public class LogEntry
{
    public string Log { get; private set; }
    public string Level { get; private set; }

    public LogEntry(string log, string level)
    {
        Log = log;
        Level = level
    }
}

public ObservableCollection<LogEntry> EventLogList
{
    get => _eventLogList;
    set => Set(ref _eventLogList, value);
}

protected sealed override void LogInfoEvent(string msg)
{ 
    EventLogList.Insert(0, new LogEntry($"{_logDate} [Info]: {msg}", "Info"));
    base.LogInfoEvent(msg);
}

protected sealed override void LogErrorEvent(string msg, Exception exception = null)
{
    if (IsScanningMode)
        StopScanningExecuteAsync();

    EventLogList.Insert(0, new LogEntry($"{_logDate} [Error]: {msg}", "Error"));
    base.LogErrorEvent(msg, exception);        
}
```

```xml
<ListView Height="230"
          ItemsSource="{Binding EventLogList}">
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <WrapPanel Width="560">
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Log}"
                             TextWrapping="Wrap">
                      <TextBlock.Style>
                          <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                              <Style.Triggers>
                                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Level}" Value="Error">
                                      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                                  </DataTrigger>
                                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Level}" Value="Info">
                                      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGray" />
                                  </DataTrigger>
                                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Level}" Value="Ok">
                                      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGreen" />
                                  </DataTrigger>
                              </Style.Triggers>
                          </Style>
                      </TextBlock.Style>
                  </TextBlock>
             </WrapPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Pls mark as solution

Comment: I have a question. I now have checkbox in my app that says Info. If this checkbox is checked all the messages will be shown in log but if not checked it will only show success and error. I have create a property in my mainviewmodel.cs called showinnfo and it is mapped to that checkbox. but i am not able to change binding. Can you help in this?

Comment: @user8549547 could you please submit a new question?

Comment: Hi. I have posted the question. Linke= https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69927221/show-log-message-on-basis-of-type